# How to retain specific keys in array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, intersection, hashset

I have an associative array

```
$preans[$id]...
```

which has a lot of data, associated with `$id`.

Also I have another array, which has

```
$affected_feature_ids[$id] = TRUE;
```

Now I want to retain in `$preans` only those indexes, which exist in `$affected_feature_ids`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$preans = array_intersect_key($preans, $affected_feature_ids);
```

> **array_intersect_key()** returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.

Comment: dont get much more elegant than that

Answer (score 3):

Quick and inelegant working solution:

```
$a = []
foreach($affected_feature_ids as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) $a[$key] = $preans[$key];
}
// Now $a has only the elements you wanted.
print_r($a); // <-- displays what you are asking for
```

One more elegant solution could be:

```
$preans = array_intersect_key($preans, array_filter($affected_feature_ids));
```

The difference with Mathei Mihai answer is that it will ignore `$affected_feature_ids` elements where `$id` is false or null. In your case it will only consider `$affected_feature_ids[$id]` when it's `true`

Now you can search for more elegant solutions!